# How to understand ndarray.reshape function?

Tags: python, numpy

The prototype of `reshape()` is that `reshape(shape, order="C")`, and the type of shape is tuple.
So we should call this function with `myarray.reshape((1000, 1, 32, 32))`, But I find that many use `myarray.reshape(1000, 1, 32, 32)`, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit of hidden flexibility built into the `reshape` method.

The keyword here needs to be explicit: you *can't* do for example:

```
myarray.reshape(1000, 1, 32, 32, "C")
```

You'll get a `TypeError`, saying that an integer is required.

(In fact, even using a tuple:

```
myarray.reshape((1000, 1, 32, 32), "C")
```

raises the `TypeError`.)

If you look at the source code (e.g., at [GitHub](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/945c308e96fb815729e8f8aeb0ad6b39b8bdf84a/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L171), you'll see that, after the keywords are parsed, there is a check for 0 or 1 arguments. In that case, the argument is interpreted as a tuple. If there are more arguments, each is interpreted as an integer and combined into a tuple as the new shape (the keyword arguments have already been taken out).

---

As to which one you should use: I guess there's not really a good answer.
You could stick with the documentation, and use tuples.
The multiple-integer-arguments convention, however, feels rather obvious.

Do stick to the convention that you, or the project you're working on, use(s). Don't use tuples and individual integer arguments in the same project.

Comment: Well, is it right that python reagard infividual integer arguments as a tuple if the prototype of this function shows that it should be tuple? For example, if prototype is `function(tuple, other = something)`, and I can call this function `function(tuple[0], tuple[1], other = something` without bracket of tuple.

Comment: No, individual integers will not automatically be collapsed into a tuple; you can simply try your example and see the result. But, the prototype here is basically `function(*args, **kwargs)`. You could argue the documentation is lying through its teeth.

Comment: Well, I think I understand when I find the prototype, thanks.

Comment: Did you follow the link I give in the answer?

Comment: Which link? The numpy's repository?

Comment: Basically, I think it Python signature is `def reshape(self, shape, *, order='C'):...`. E.g. order is a keyword-only argument.