# Understanding how to specify the newshape parameter for numpy's reshape()

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python data analysis, and trying to figure out how to manipulate a multi-dimensional array to a different dimension.  Tutorials or forums online don't explain how to specify the parameters of "newshape" for `numpy.reshape(a, newshape, order='C')`

Here is an example I am trying to understand. It would be very helpful if someone could explain line 4.

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.arrange(8).reshape( (8,1) ) 
b = np.repeat(a1,8,axis=1)
c = b.reshape(2,4,2,4)               # line 4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A similar question from a week ago: [How to understand ndarray.reshape function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928669/how-to-understand-ndarray-reshape-function)

`np.reshape(a, newshape)` gets recast as `a.reshape(newshape)`.  But `a.reshape` is a builtin, compiled method.  So the details of how it handles `newshape` are hidden (to Python programmers).

The examples show that `newshape` can be a tuple, or separate numbers.  But in a sense, even the separate numbers case uses a tuple.  The arguments to a function are passed as a tuple.

This perhaps is most obvious with indexing.  `a[:,1,3]` is translated by the interpreter into `a.__getitem__((slice(None),1,3))` call.  And in fact `a[(:,1,3)]` is allowed, as is `ind = (slice(None),1,3); a[ind]`.

It's easy to write your own function that makes the extra layer of `()` optional:

```
In [58]: def foo(*args):
    ...:     if len(args)==1:
    ...:         args = args[0]
    ...:     print(args)
    ...:     

In [59]: foo(1,2,3)
(1, 2, 3)

In [60]: foo((1,2,3))
(1, 2, 3)
```

I need to refine it a bit more to treat these 2 cases the same:

```
In [61]: foo(1)
1    
In [62]: foo((1,))
(1,)
```

If I'd defined the function as `def foo(arg):`, then I'd have to use a tuple if I wanted to give it several numbers.

Hopefully this gives a sense of why most experienced Python programmers aren't bothered by these differences.  Often a tuple is just a convenient way of grouping values.  It can add clarity, but isn't always needed. The coder can go either direction - gloss over their presence or not, or made a big deal of it.

===================

The reshape method is defined in `numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c` (in the github numpy repository).  While written in `c` it appears to be the equivalent of

```
 def reshape(self, *args, **kwargs):
     n = len(args)
     if n<=1:
         newshape = <parse args[0] in one way>
     else:
         newshape = <parse args in another way>
     return PyArray_Newshape(self, newshape, order)
```

In any case it's being parsed so these are all the same:

```
shape=(2,3)
np.arange(6).reshape(shape)
np.arange(6).reshape(*shape)
np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
np.arange(6).reshape((2,3))
np.arange(6).reshape((2,)+(3,))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `newshape` argument has to be passed as a tuple (or something compatible) to `numpy.reshape`. But here's the catch: all the non-keyword arguments passed to `numpy.ndarray.reshape` (e.g. `b.reshape` in your example) will be caught by the argument `newshape`. This means that the following are equivalent and valid:

```
# b = np.random.rand(2*4*2*4)
np.reshape(b,(2,4,2,4))
np.ndarray.reshape(b,(2,4,2,4))
np.ndarray.reshape(b,2,4,2,4)
b.reshape((2,4,2,4))
b.reshape(2,4,2,4)
```

While this throws an error:

```
np.reshape(b,2,4,2,4)
```

The key difference is that `np.reshape` and `np.ndarray.reshape` are different animals, and `b.reshape` is the bound version of the latter.

---

You should also compare `help(np.reshape)`:

```
reshape(a, newshape, order='C')
    Gives a new shape to an array without changing its data.
```

with `help(b.reshape)`:

```
a.reshape(shape, order='C')

Returns an array containing the same data with a new shape.
```

As you can see, `np.reshape` doesn't have any information about specific arrays, so if you want to reshape something using it, you have to *explicitly* pass it as a first argument. On the other hand, `b.reshape` is bound to the variable `b`, so it only has to be given a new shape, and optionally an `order` keyword argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another perspective for understanding the `shape` of an array if that is part of what you are asking. The `shape` parameter `(2, 4, 2, 4)` specifies the length along each of the four different axises of the array. If you conceptually consider it as list of lists then it means the length from the out most list to inner most list. For example, for your array c here, if you check:

```
len(c)
# 2

len(c[0])            # same result if you check c[1]
# 4

len(c[0][0])
# 2

len(c[0][0][0])
# 4
```

This matches the shape parameter. Or may be a better example is 2D array, which is matrix:

```
a = np.array(range(9)) 
a
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

b = a.reshape(3,3)
b
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 5],
#        [6, 7, 8]])
```

As you can see, `b` has the same data as `a` but has a two dimension structure and each has length of 3 as specified in the shape parameter. And now if you check:

```
len(b)
# 3

len(b[0])
# 3
```

Which gives the shape parameter back.